# SharePoint Framework gulp serve localhost sent an invalid response

Tags: sharepoint-framework

I'm testing a newly created webpart locally using the `gulp serve` command after launching the gulp `trust-dev-cert` for certification installation, the local workbench opens up but all browsers are displaying the same error. Here's a screenshot from google chrome :

[image]

What I've tried :

- Disabling firewall

I've googled and googled but with no success.

Does anyone have an idea about what's happening ?

Comment: definitely looks like a cert issue. Have you tried Fiddling? Or running trust-cert again?

Comment: I've used Fiddler and it showed 200 http code. I've also removed the certificate using gulp "untrust-dev-cert" and reinstalled it again, no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give a look to the tip of Waldek Mastykarz if you are using latest LTS of Node.js here, it solved the issue for me (no need to disable firewall) : 
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1002

Comment: Hi Patrick, thank you for your answer, it's working now. I've added a global environment variable like this : Key = "NODE_NO_HTTP2" and Value = "1". After that, we should close any command line or PowerShell session and restart again and it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10, Node version 8.9.1, SPFx version 1.4.0 below is the solution:

Add System variable

> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> System Variables)

- Variable name: NODE_NO_HTTP2
- Variable value: 1

Don't forget to restart terminal.

Comment: These does not help in 2019. Look here for working solution: sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/230115/5658